# Validation setup

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Now I am working on to create a validation when user didn't input which user will handle the task. The user_id input is stetted in a option list. In the TaskController:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {

        $task = new Task();
        $task->description = $request->get('description'); 
        $task->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
        $val = Task::Inputvalidator($request->validated()); 
        $file = $request->file('file');
        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            foreach($file as $file){
                $file->move('storage/uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
                $task->image =\Storage::url("uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"][0]);
                $task->image2 =\Storage::url("uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"][1]);
                $task->save();
            }

        }
        $task->task_date = request('task_date');
        $dt1 = Carbon::now();
        $dt2 = Carbon::parse($task->task_date);
        if($dt1 > $dt2){
            echo $messages->first("You have to chose after today as the deadline");
            return redirect('/');
        }else{
            $dt3 = $dt1->diffInDays($dt2);
            $task->expired = $dt3;
        }


        $duplicate = Task::where('description',$request->get('description'))->first();
        $duplicateUser = Task::where('user_id',$request->get('user_id'))->first();
        $duplicateDate = Task::where('task_date',$request->get('task_date'))->first();
        if($duplicate&&$duplicateDate&&$duplicateUser)
        {
            return redirect('/')->with('popup', 'duplicate');
        } 
        else
        { 
            $task->save();
        } 

        return redirect('/'); 
    }
```

In my task model:

```
 protected $fillable = ['name','user_id','description','task_date'];

    public function user()
    {   
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public static function Inputvalidator(Request $request){

            $rules = array(
            'user_id' =>'required|not_in:0'
            );
        $this->validate($request,$rules);
    }

    protected function getInputCredentials(Request $request){

        $validator = $this->inputvalidator($request);

        var_dump($validator); die();

        if($validator->passes())
        {
            return[
                'user_id' => Request::input('user_id')
            ];

            return true;
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors();
        }
    }
```

But I now I come up different error, too few arguments, request need to instance. Now under this code, it said undefined variable rules. I am not too sure what should I fix this code. Can you help me to solve and check this code right or not? Thank you.

Comment: You have those methods inside the Model?

Comment: I would suggest a different approach. Such as creating a request class that holds the validation and import and use that in your controller. I can give an example if you would like. May I see the controller you are calling from?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: @jeremykenedy Thank you. "The controller you are calling from" may I ask what do you mean? Cause in my case, I only use task controller and task model. So I am not too sure how should I answer your question. Sorry about that.

Comment: The method in the controller that contains these: $task->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
$val = Task::Inputvalidator($this->validate($request,$rules));

Comment: and for future instead of `var_dump($validator); die();` just use `dd($validator)`, dd is a laravel helper for dump and die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run `php artisan make:request TaskRequest`
2. Fill the new `app\Http\Requests\TashRequest.php` file with:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TaskRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' =>'required|not_in:0',
        ];
    }
}
```

3. In the controller do something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

...

use App\Http\Requests\TaskRequest;

...

class YourControllerName extends Controller
{

...

    public function yourMethodName(TaskRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();

...
```

If the validation above fails it will return back with a 422 and the messages automatically ready to be pulled from the message bag.

Sources:

- https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation

Example in the wild:

- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/larablog/blob/master/app/Http/Requests/StoreTagRequest.php
- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/larablog/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/TagController.php#L7
- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/larablog/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/TagController.php#L56

Comment: Thank you. That's really help me to get understanding. But I not quite get it. YourMethodName this function is for validation calling?

Comment: That is just a placeholder for the method name in your controller. That's not the actual methods name. I do not know what your controller looks like so It's just a placeholder.

Comment: The take away from that line is `TaskRequest $request` instead of using the general Request class of `Request $request`

Comment: I have make an update of my controller. This is the place I would like to work on. So, I am wondering how to work on the validation setup?

Comment: I have make the changes. But now it come up 403 error screen. So how can I fix it?

Comment: 403 is unauthorized. In your new request class did you set `authorize()` to return `true`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing **$this->validate($request,$rules) parameter** inside **Inputvalidator()** function, simply pass the **$request** variable as the function expects.

```
//TaskController

$task->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
$val = Task::Inputvalidator($request);
```

Instead of using Request Validation inside the model for reusability, Laravel provides [Creating Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests) under the hood for simplicity and understandable.

Comment: @lizenshakya Thank you for your help. I have try this method, but it come out "Using $this when not in object context" error. So what should I fix under this error?

Comment: `$this->validate()` function is a function that exists inside `Controller`. I recommend using Laravel Request Validation instead of using inside model. Hope it helps